# Post id algorithm in Wordpress

Tags: posts

How new post ids are determined in Wordpress and how can I change it? I want to start my post ids from 1 and make it a 4 digit number.

Comment: I wouldn't start meddling with post IDs for aesthetics, you can cause all sorts of issues. The answer is likely to involve SQL modifications which might be undone in the future. Can you provide some context? Is there a particular reason you cannot use slugs?